# XCode UIWebView Specific Element fro URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview, uiwebview, element

In my project I have an UIWebView in which I display some content.

But for special URLs, I just want the WebView to display a specific part of the WebPage.

For example, if my WebView is about to load http://google.de/ it should only display the search bar without all the other elements.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 1st why? 2nd the only way you could do this would be to trim the HTML for the specific pages. Not a simple task.

Comment: In my webview i am loading a webpage wich contains a WebM video (wich ios does not Support, the webm is decoded on the server and played converted). I can dowload the webm file but im not able to decode and play the webm file. So my idea is to load the original desktop url and only displaying the part where the decoded converted video is playing